# TextView disappears when more than one line is drawn on rotated canvas

Tags: android, view, textview, android-canvas

I am having a very strange problem on gingerbread and below (works on honeycomb and above) where a textview with more than 1 line of text will completely disappear when drawn onto a canvas that has been rotated around either the x or y axis (3d rotation that is). Everything works fine with one line of text but fails at even a 1 degree angle with 2 lines on text.

So my question is, Why does this happen and is there a fix for it? 
My back up plan is to draw the text to a non-rotated bitmap and than draw that bitmap to the rotated canvas.

this is how i am applying the rotation:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Camera camera = new Camera();
camera.rotateX(30);
camera.getMatrix(matrix);

matrix.preTranslate(-getWidth() / 2, -getHeight() / 2);
matrix.postTranslate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);

canvas.concat(matrix);
```

Comment: i am having the same problem, I think. I rotate a view with a textview inside of it. The parts of the view that are not text are shown during rotation from Y:0 to 180, but the textview disappears and then reappears when the rotation is at 180. If I stop the rotation at Y:20deg then the text doesn't show. As in it shows at Y:0 but not at Y:20 and does also show at Y:180.